# React Native: Background Image not filling the entire app

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to get the background image to take up the entire space on the screen

[image]

As you can see from the image this does not seem to be working. I think it may be something to do with the scroll view but unfortunately I cannot figure it out.

Ideally want to use flex box for the solution.

```js
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={require('./src/assets/foodflixIMG.jpg')}
              style={styles.image}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    height: '100%',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'grey',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: try resizeMode="cover"

Comment: Didn't work but thanks for the effort

Comment: The image is broken. Maybe the problem is because the image is being wrapped inside `SafeAreaView`?

Comment: Unfortunately neither of your suggestions worked. The image is perfectly fine. I can increase the image size using px but I automatically want it to grow depending on mobile size.

Comment: What I meant by the "image is broken" is that I can't see any image because it is broken in your description. Fix it

Comment: Oh I see. Stackoverflow links it to here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOmF5.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your code something like this:

```
<ImageBackground 
            source={require('./assets/main.jpg')}
            style={{height:"100%", 
            width:"100%", flex:1}}
            > 
              <SafeAreaView>
              <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                 <Text>Hello</Text>
                </View>
              </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>

           </ImageBackground>
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I love you haha I spent far too long on this. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Iam glad that I helped you.